# Why Google officially to end some old search console features?

Tags: google, google-search-console, search

Here are some of the upcoming changes in Search Console that google planning on making towards end of March, 2019:

- Crawl errors in the new Index Coverage report
- Sitemaps data in Index Coverage
- Using the URL inspection tool to fetch as Google
- User-management is now in settings
- Structured data dashboard to dedicated reports per vertical
- Letting go of some old features

Here is the details : https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2019/01/focusing-on-new-search-console.html

Why they are doing this? How these will effect us?

Comment: I haven't seen Google publish its reasoning behind these changes.  Without word from Google, we are likely just to be guessing here.    They also may have separate reasons for each of different reports which makes this question very broad.